# Eclipse autocomplete broken

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

Eclipse autocomplete is not working and is always telling me merely "No Default Proposals".

This is true whether I try to autocomplete for code under java.util or in my own project.

I'm running Eclipse 3.5.2 on Lucid Lynx using java-6-openjdk.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced

All the Java options were turned off.  Don't know how this happened or why it's not always on :o/

Comment: I just updated the Android Support Library within the SDK and the auto-complete stopped working.  It turns out all the Java options got turned off.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I got this error when i created an eclipse account to synchronize my settings lol. Somehow 90% of them were automatically checked off ?..
Anyways thanks a bunch @Ben!

Answer (score 2):

Open eclipse and go to the following:

```
Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced
```

Select all checkboxes and click Ok.

Comment: Not sure why you would post the exact same answer, more than a year later?

Comment: @SanderVerhagen I'd call it like i see it. (e.g. reputation farming XD)