# Eclipse autocomplete not even showing up

Tags: java, eclipse

Using Eclipse 2018-09 with Java 11, autocomplete seems to have stopped working. It's not that the menu is blank (like in [Eclipse autocomplete broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481606/eclipse-autocomplete-broken)), it's that when I press cmd+space, it doesn't do anything. I tried the solutions involving the advanced Content Assist preferences (from the above link), but they don't work. I also tried closing and reopening the project and quitting and reopening Eclipse. Does anyone have any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the keyboard shortcut is still correct?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? How would I check that?

Comment: When it really goes wrong with `Eclipse`, don't fear to exit it, delete your `.metadata` folder, and restart it. You will have to set again you preferences of code format and others (if you didnt't exported them before), but most of the times it clears all the little troubles that accumulated from months to months and with `Eclipse` upgrades.

Comment: @Marc Thanks for the advice. I tried that, but the autocomplete still doesn't show up.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working. In fact it wasn't a problem with Eclipse at all but a side-effect of my adding a new input scheme to my Mac, which automatically triggered the default keyboard shortcut--ctrl-space--for switching between keyboard input schemes. I turned off that keyboard shortcut and ctrl-space works again--not very smart of me not to think of that. Thanks for all the help.